# Can not install android studio on mac

Tags: android, android-studio

Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin_x64-7243153.zip
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Emulator: Connection reset.
"Install Android Emulator (revision: 30.5.4)" failed.

showing when I am trying to install android studio on my macbook pro m1 .New to android studio Idk what to do

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to Android Studio.
The problem is with the connectivity.
Check your internet connection and make sure it is stable, if you are using any proxy disable it and try again.